# Discrepancy between count of rows and rows returned in results tab: SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count

I am trying to find the number of unique IDs in my table and these two lines of code give me two different results:

```
select distinct [ID] 
from df1

-- The table returned in results tab total of 2,300,000 rows

select distinct count(ID) as ID 
from df1

-- The count of the output is 97,000,000
```

Is the reason for this discrepancy because SQL Server limits the number of rows in the results tab?

Comment: Try select count(distinct ID) from df1    Cleary  ID is NOT unique.   count(ID) is essentially count(*).  OR you've got a ton of NULL values  :)

Comment: This worked! Both are showing the same results now. Just for clarification, was the issue that 'distinct' was not being properly applied to the ID in the second line of code? With the fix you suggested, now sql knowns to only count 'distinct' IDs?

Comment: Imagine if you could set up a testbed with a few rows...

Comment: @P.Salmon not sure what you mean

Comment: @P.Salmon is referring to tools like https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` applies a distinct to the whole set of final columns and values. In this case, you only have one row and one value: the count. So the `DISTINCT` was meaningless. The actual result was not distincting, as mentioned. In theory you could do an even more pointless `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)...`